# SciPy minimize constraints - matrix sums

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to optimize over a 3D array, where all of the entries along the z-axis sum to 1 (that is, the sum of all entries with the same (x, y) coordinate is 1 for all choices of x and y). How do I express this as a constraint to SciPy's minimize?

Comment: Do you mean scipy.optimize.minimize?

Comment: Apologies, you're right. Editing question

Comment: When you want to optimize something, you always need to be able to name the variables (collected in a vector) which may be varied and a function which maps this vector to scalar, which is supposed to be minimized. Additionally functions, which limit the domain of your vector are allowed. All I can read from your question is a constrain without explicit variables. Please clarify.

Comment: At least show the target function that you want to optimize for. But based on what you described, `scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp()` seems to be the right choice.